# Error in Adding data into Recycleview which are fetched from server

Tags: android, json, android-layout, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

I am trying to get strings(usernames) from Server wanna put it into Recycle.For that, I am using JSON to fetch data and Asynctask to generate a new thread.I successfully getting usernames from the server but failed to put them in recycleview.

**This is my Mainactivity.java**

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BufferedReader reader;
    private String content;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    Adapter madapter;
    List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new ApiAsyncTask().execute();
    }

    private class ApiAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            getData();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv123);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager());
            data.add("name");

            Dataadapter madapter = new Dataadapter(data);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(madapter);
        }
    }

    private void getData(){
        try {

            URL url = new URL("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments");
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(false);

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;


            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                // Append server response in string
                sb.append(line + " ");
            }

            // Append Server Response To Content String
            content = sb.toString();
            Log.e("TAG", "Response is -> " + content);
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(content);
            for(int i=0;i<=4;i++){
            JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
            Log.e("TAG", "Username is -> " + name);}



        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**This is my Adapter**

```
 public class Dataadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    public TextView textView;
    private List<String> data;
    public Dataadapter(List<String> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv);

        }}
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View dataView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.container, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(dataView);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        textView.setText(data.get(position));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }
}
```

Using 2 XML files.One is Mainactivity.xml and other is Container.xml.Please help me on how to show usernames (which I fetched from the server)into recycleview.For now, when I run the app, it just showing the layout only.Not getting any username in that layout.But in my log, I can see the usernames.Thank u

Comment: In getDate() method you only print names to log, you not add them to your list

Comment: Please send the proper code sir.Also, want to know that what I should write in recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager()); Thank u

Answer (score 1):

Just add the objects to your list

```
for(int i=0;i<=4;i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                data.add(jsonObject.getString("name")); 
            }
```

And the LinearLayoutManager constructor takes one parameter, a Context.

In your onPostExecute, do this -

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, I tested it and it's working.

Here's **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    BufferedReader reader;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    Dataadapter madapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv123);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        madapter = new Dataadapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(madapter);

        new ApiAsyncTask().execute();
    }

    private class ApiAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {
        @Override
        protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            return getData();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> names) {
            madapter.updateData(names);
        }
    }

    private List<String> getData() {
        List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments");
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(false);

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Append server response in string
                sb.append(line);
            }

            // Append Server Response To Content String
            String content = sb.toString();
            Log.e("TAG", "Response is -> " + content);

            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(content);

            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                Log.e("TAG", "Username is -> " + name);
                data.add(name);
            }
         } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
        Log.d(TAG, "getData: " + data.size());
        return data;
    }
}
```

and here's **Dataadapter.java**

```
public class Dataadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    public TextView textView;
    private List<String> data;

    public Dataadapter() {
        data = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View dataView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.container, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(dataView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        textView.setText(data.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public void updateData(List<String> data) {
        this.data = data;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

The data returned from the API endpoint contains 500 items, I used 50 instead to load faster.

Answer (score 0):

You should not make holder's textView as adapter's local variable and assign value on holder's constructor. Since `ViewHolder` may be reused and parsed to `Adapter.onBindViewHolder()` and then the textView used in `onBindViewHolder()` method is not the textView in holder( the `ViewHolder` constructor not called). You can make textView as `MyViewHolder`'s variable and use `holder.getTextView().setText(item)` to set text.